# How to insert angular js code?

Tags: angularjs, google-api

I'm actually doing an app for a stage, which has to be responsive design. So it has to work on Mobile, Computer and Tablet. For this app I need to use the google api Place Autocomplete. The problem with that is that it doesn't work on mobile, whether it's iOS or android... on another forum i found a piece of code which is the following, supposed to resolve this problem :

```html
.directive('disableTap', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        // Find google places div
        _.findIndex(angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.pac-container')), function(container) {
          // disable ionic data tab
          container.setAttribute('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
          // leave input field if google-address-entry is selected
          container.onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('autocomplete').blur();
          };
        });
      },500);
    }
  };
});
```

The problem is that i've never used Angular JS in my life and i do'nt have the time to learn it now, maybe after i'm done with the app... and this function is supposed to make it works on mobile, but i don't know how to use it. Could you guys give me a hand and explain me how to insert this code in my project and how to use it? I'm really in need and some help would be very appreciated. by the way, i'm not english native so if you didn't udnerstand something in my post just tell i'll try to say it better ^-^

I hope you will be able to help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the same in jQuery, but you have to adapt it yourself. You require also the underscore.js library. Hope this helps.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // Find google places div
    _.findIndex($(document.querySelectorAll('.pac-container')), function(container) {
      // disable ionic data tab
      container.setAttribute('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
      // leave input field if google-address-entry is selected
      container.onclick = function() {
        $('#autocomplete').blur();
      };
    });
  },500);
```

Comment: Thank you guy for the help, i didn't realize it could be transformed in jquery so easily... i'll have no problem to find out the solution with this now :). I hope it will works now! Thanks again